# Telegram Bot: Is it possible to get userid using username?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

As the title says, is it possible to get userid using username?
I mean, I would like to add a feature to my bot that tells you the user id from an other user using his username.

Does Telegram API give an option to do this?

Comment: check out the updated answer

Comment: @MohammedSohail I'll check it this weekend

Comment: For anyone interested, yes there is a way to resolve a userid from username. check my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you mean by nickname is the `username` and userid is the unique `id` as described in the API documentation.**It is still possible** to do a reverse lookup using a bot.

This is possible with a boosted version of the Official Telegram API, known as [PWRTelegram API](https://github.com/pwrtelegram/pwrtelegram)

I quote from the documentation.

> Resolving of usernames not only with channels and groups but also with
>   normal users and bots

Update:

[Here](https://github.com/kamikazechaser/tg-resolve) is a library I made for this purpose:

Update 2:

I no longer maintain the above library, you can however still resolve usernames with a td-cli binary.

Comment: Ok, what API call do you use?

Comment: I guess because you just say "Yeah, it's possible", but not how.

Comment: Can you give us an example how you get the userid of a user @foo?

Answer (score 6):

The solution by [Mohammod Sohail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37736418/10014361) is partially wrong.

There are ways to get a `user_id` from `username`, but online tools mentioned above use more than the bot API. They have a telegram client running on their server.
That said there is a trick to get a `user_id` from `username` purely with bot API (doen't always work).

Lets say you are chatting with your friend `X` and you want to know his `user_id`. To get the `user_id`, forward one of your conversations to your bot. The bot will get the message author's `first name`, `username`, `user_id`, `timestamp`, and so on in JSON format. Now you can extract the `user_id` from that. Note that this also works even if the user does not have a `username`, or if its a channel or another bot.

Here is an bot implementation of the above:

I've forwarded one of my friend's message to the bot [@get_id_bot](https://t.me/get_id_bot)
Then the bot returns the username and id of my friend's account

[image: GET ID BOT]

Comment: This is nice solution, but it doesn't work if user set forward privacy for his messages.

Comment: just want to say thank you for using my bot get_id_bot, I think I will add the getChat method mentioned in the answer of @danogentili to my bot

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [pwrtelegram bot API](https://pwrtelegram.xyz) to resolve usernames of bots and normal users.

It will automagically resolve the usernames you provide in the chat_id parameter using a built in mtproto client.

You can use usernames of bots and normal users in every method that requires the chat_id parameter, but to get info about a user/bot you can use the [getChat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) method.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible right now.

Comment: Hmmm... Damn... I will have to do something different to do what I want. Thanks anyway.